# Should I offer to or Supply an Award Nomination Form to the Nominee?

Tags: professionalism, communication, recommendation-letter

So make this short: a teammate on the ~30 person team I currently lead won a national award, and I would like to brag on them a bit. I am the one who submitted the nomination, which includes some endorsement letters from colleagues and an assessment of the nominee’s work (all highly laudatory).

I would like to offer the nomination packet to my colleague at the small (virtual in 2021) celebration we are going to have for them. The authors of the nomination were never told one way or the other if their writings would be shared, and I don’t think any would object to their thoughts being made known to the nominee. Still, I am not 100% sure how I feel about this. Is it typical (in the US or internally) to present an awardee with their nomination packet they previously have not seen? Are there good reasons for or against this?

Comment: Do you feel that wining the award is not good enough for this teammate?

Comment: @sf02 No, I think the award was great recognition for a job well done. I was just thinking it would be nice for them to know what their colleagues think of the work done and what lead to the award itself

Comment: What benefit is there in sharing the packet?  What are the risks? The risks certainly outweigh the benefits here.

Answer (score 5):

**Ask the writers first**

I have put some pretty sensitive things in nomination letters, the kind of things that people would not want shared but they deserve to be recognized for and in my view help them win the award. Sometimes they have included things that I only learned in passing or that they did privately for one person who later passed the knowledge on. I edited a nomination letter from someone who never told the nominee of the impact that they had on their life and was somewhat embarrassed to share even with the award group.

This is for a work award, so I expect the nominations to be a bit more professional and less personal (compared to teachers and fellow students), but there is still the risk of there being things the authors do not want shared.